# IBM Watson Speech-to-Text JavaScript SDK: how to get messages?

Tags: javascript, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I'm seeing the word transcriptions, either in the browser or in the console, but I'm not seeing the messages such as `{'state': 'listening'}`. More importantly, I'm not seeing the results such as `{"results": [{"alternatives": [{"transcript": "name the mayflower "}],"final": true}],"result_index": 0}`.

I read the [RecognizeStream documentation](http://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/speech-javascript-sdk/master/RecognizeStream.html) and tried this code:

```
stream.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log(message);
  });
```

but that doesn't work. I tried `object_mode` in both `true` and `false` but the output was the same.

Here's the full code that I'm using:

```
document.querySelector('#button').onclick = function () {

  var stream = WatsonSpeech.SpeechToText.recognizeMicrophone({
    token: token,
    model: 'en-US_BroadbandModel',
    keywords: ["Colorado"],
    keywords_threshold: 0.50,
    word_confidence: true,
    // outputElement: '#output' // send text to browser instead of console
    object_mode: false
  });

  stream.setEncoding('utf8'); // get text instead of Buffers for on data events

  stream.on('data', function(data) { // send text to console instead of browser
    console.log(data);
  });

  stream.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });

  document.querySelector('#stop').onclick = function() {
    stream.stop();
  };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `recognizeMicrophone()` method is a helper that chains together a number of streams. The `message` event is fired on one of the streams in the middle. But, you can get access to that one at `stream.recognizeStream` - it's always attached to the last one in the chain in order to support cases like this.

So, in your code, it should look something like this:

```
stream.recognizeStream.on('message', function(frame, data) {
  console.log('message', frame, data)
});
```

However, that is mainly there for debugging. The results JSON should be emitted on the `data` event, if you set `objectMode: true` and *don't* call `stream.setEncoding('utf8');`.

(This is somewhat different from Watson Node.js SDK, if you're familiar with it's behavior. There are plans to unify the two, but never enough time...)

Comment: Thanks, that worked! And can you upvote my question?